# read_parquet and merge schema

Tags: dask, parquet, pyarrow, dask-dataframe

I have a lot of parquet files which are partitioned by `YEAR/MONTH/DAY`, which I read in with `read_parquet(PATH, engine="pyarrow")`.
All parquets have the columns `"column_1", column_2"`. However, newer files have an additional column: `"column_1", column_2", "column_3"`. When I read in the files all data from `column_1` and `column_2` is loaded, however, `column_3`is completely ignored.

Is there a way to enforce loading the data of `column_3` with `read_parquet` on the partitioned data and simply fill it with `Null` for the files that do not contain this column? I'd like to avoid looping over the files.

Comment: note that fastparquet does allow for this kind of schema evolution. It should work fine with dask, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

`pyarrow.parquet.read_parquet` will try to unify the schema of the parquet files that are loaded.

To do so `pyarrow` uses as reference the schema of the first parquet file it finds. So that's why you are seeing the data from the older data (missing column_3).

Take an example with 2 tables with different schemas:

```py
import pyarrow as  pa
import pyarrow.parquet as  pq

table1 = pa.table({
    "column_1": [1, 2, 3],
    "column_2": ["A", "B", "C"],
})
pq.write_table(table1, "table1.parquet")

table2= pa.table({
    "column_1": [4 , 5, 6],
    "column_2": ["D", "E", "F"],
    "column_3": ["New", "Data", "Here"],
})
pq.write_table(table2, "table2.parquet")
```

Reading table1 first gives you a table with table1's schema:

```py
pq.read_table(['table1.parquet', "table2.parquet"])
```

| column_1 | column_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |
| 6 | F |

Reading table2 first gives you a table with table2's schema:

```py
pq.read_table(['table2.parquet', "table1.parquet"])
```

| column_1 | column_2 | column_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | D | New |
| 5 | E | Data |
| 6 | F | Here |
| 1 | A |  |
| 2 | B |  |
| 3 | C |  |

Unfortunately you can't specify which table is read first. What you can do instead is specify the schema you expect:

```py
pq.read_table(['table1.parquet', "table2.parquet"], schema=table2.schema)
```

| column_1 | column_2 | column_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A |  |
| 2 | B |  |
| 3 | C |  |
| 4 | D | New |
| 5 | E | Data |
| 6 | F | Here |

Comment: Thanks, this is useful! However, as I understood with ```pq.read_table``` I have to explicitly tell the method the files I want to read in, i.e., there is no asterisk option like ```pq.read_table('*.parquet')```to read in all the partitioned parquets at once?

Comment: You can pass `pq.read_table` a directory, it will scan for parquet file. But I assume you are using dask version of `read_parquet`. You should be able to pass it the `schema` argument as well and it will pass it to `pq.read_table`.