# dask's read_parquet reads in files that should be filtered out when loading schema

Tags: python, pandas, dask, parquet, pyarrow

I'm running into an issue where I'm saving different parquet files with slightly different schema, but which have shared partition columns. I have created the following as a minimal reproducible example:

```
from dask import dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import shutil

def save_parquet():
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1], "B": [1]})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [2], "C": [2]})
    df1.to_parquet("test.parquet", partition_cols=["A"])
    df2.to_parquet("test.parquet", partition_cols=["A"])

def load_parquet():
    filters = [[
        ("A", "==", 2)
    ]]
    ddf = dd.read_parquet("test.parquet", columns=["A", "C"], filters=filters)

def main():
    save_parquet()
    load_parquet()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Running the above causes the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/backends.py", line 133, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/core.py", line 578, in read_parquet
    meta, index, columns = set_index_columns(meta, index, columns, auto_index_allowed)
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/core.py", line 1487, in set_index_columns
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The following columns were not found in the dataset {'C'}
The following columns were found Index(['B', 'A'], dtype='object')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mre.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "mre.py", line 23, in main
    load_parquet()
  File "mre.py", line 15, in load_parquet
    ddf = dd.read_parquet("test.parquet", columns=["A", "C"], filters=filters)
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/backends.py", line 135, in wrapper
    raise type(e)(
ValueError: An error occurred while calling the read_parquet method registered to the pandas backend.
Original Message: The following columns were not found in the dataset {'C'}
The following columns were found Index(['B', 'A'], dtype='object')
```

My expectation would be that the `("A", "==", 2)` filter should stop us from loading the schema from `df1`, and regardless of whether it loads `df1` or not, that it should be able to find the `"C"` column from `df2`. Am I missing something here?

Changing the `columns` field to `columns=["A", "B"]` successfully reads in the data, so it feels what I'm trying to do should be possible somehow.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76787896/read-parquet-and-merge-schema) indicates that read_parquet reads the schema from the first parquet file it encounters, but that you can specify a schema to avoid this.

Specifying a `schema` like

```
import pyarrow as pa

...

ddf = dd.read_parquet("test.parquet", columns=["A", "C"], filters=filters, schema=pa.schema({"A": pa.int64(), "C": pa.int64()}))
```

still triggers the exception.

Specifying a `schema` without specifying `columns` doesn't trigger the exception, but returns a dask dataframe without the "C" column (seemingly regardless of what was in the schema):

```
>>> print(ddf.columns)
Index(['B', 'A'], dtype='object')
```

Is there a way to prevent `read_parquet` from using the .parquet files that should be filtered out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a somewhat silly workaround.

dask.dataframe.read_parquet can take a list of parquet files within partitions (rather than the top-level parquet folder). I just used path globbing to manually filter down to only the relevant parquet files I wanted to use (based on partition folder) and pass that list in directly.

Answer (score 1):

To point out, that (py)arrow does not support schema evolution. Fastparquet intends to do so in the near future, poor (i.e., likely to break) support being currently available.

```
>>> pd.read_parquet("test.parquet", engine="fastparquet", dtypes={"C": "float", "B": "float", "A": "int"})

    C    B  A
0 NaN  1.0  1
1 NaN  NaN  2
```